# How to set accessibility priority in android

Tags: android, accessibility

When submit button is clicked, it is reading all the `EditText` error message which was previously set in "`setError`" method.
But if any notification is received in between, i need to give priority to notification. But right now it is reading the notification after all the error messages. How to set the priority for accessibility.

Comment: can you more specific and elaborate it more

Comment: I have 4 edit text in xml. i have set validation error messages as inline error message. so, it is showing error message ["Invalid Usernae"] above the edit text. while reading this error message, notification may receive. whenever notification will come that needs to will read first

Comment: I believe you break accessibility guidelines if you switch focus to different places on the screen arbitrarily, specially if talkback is halfway reading an element and it's expected to stop and move on to a new thing.